# Auto update form fields as completing

Tags: javascript

In my web app, when a user selects an item in a `dropdown box`, the `next dropdown box is updated with conditional options`. I have created a script to allow for templates of the fields, but the `second dropdown box does not update to allow me to assign a value to it.`

Example: [www.mywebsite.com?template=newcust](http://www.mywebsite.com?template=newcust)

In the header I have:

```
if (isset($_GET['template'])) {
  $templ = $_GET['template'];

  if ($templ == "newcust") {
    $autoname = "New Customer";
    $c1f = "city"; //"join_date"
    $c1w = 1; //1=is equal to, 2=is not equal to, 3=is great than, 4=is less than
}
```

So in this example,  1 would load with `"city"`, while  2 would need to display just the valid fields (is equal to, is not equal 2) and select `"is equal to"` by default. But if `"join date"` is put into `$c1f`, then all 4 options would need to be available.

When doing this manually it works fine, I'm trying to get this to auto-update the fields when the user selects to start off with a template.

I hope this gives enough background info. Let me know if I need to share anything else.
Thanks

Comment: You have to do this in JavaScript. PHP only runs when the form is submitted.

Comment: That's what I figured, and I have a "change" function for the option that updates it when manually selected, but I don't know how to automatically do this.  Probably need to capture the URL parameter in JS as well.
So basically I'll need a new function when the page loads that will capture the parameter, assign the variables, and update the necessary option input fields so it can assign the variables to the input fields.

Comment: Don't make edits like this: If you've completely changed tech stack, then this is a new question, and you should delete the PHP related original and post a new JS related one instead. Or, remove all the old code and description from your post, because it's got nothing to do with your new situation. But: only _if_ you run into a problem, because you switched to JS, so you have a new round of searching and researching to do. What did you already find? How did that not help? [Asking a good question](/help/how-to-ask) is important.